# inputbox with buttons in google spreadsheet script

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create some type of inputbox in a google sheets script

something like this:

```
Browser.inputbox("do you want to print before submitting",YES_NO)
```

if a person clicks yes, then the return command will stop the script.  If the person clicks no then the script will continue (to submit the user data)

I can't find any examples of using the response for the inputbox
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Browser.inputbox("do you want to print before submitting",YES_NO) == 'yes') {
    print();
} else {
    save();
}
```

Also, I think it's **Google Apps Script** not **Google Sheets Script.**